# Is it possible to auto-expand the Alert when received?

Tags: macos, alert

so i JUST noticed today, that if you hover over the lower boundary of an osx Alert, or notification, you can expand it to read the whole message / text / ect. however, once its closed, the next one will go back to the original 2 line mode. 
Is there a way to open it to the full size, always? [image]